# downloading DEM for free

Tags: dem, data

I need to download a DEM in WGS format for Nepal ( around 86 degrees longitude and 27 degrees latitude), that can be exported to a GIS as raster for analysis. Does anyone know of any good, free data source?

Comment: You might want to add the resolution you are looking for also.

Answer (score 5):

If you go to the [Earth Explorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) web site you can download several DEMs. For Nepal they have the 30m AsterGDEM and the 90m Void Filled SRTM. The 1 arc second (30m) SRTM is not available yet (12/12/2014) but I believe it should be ready in the near future

Comment: Another source for a void filled 90m SRTM DEM is [CGIAR](http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/) - they implemented Reuters (2007) improvement algorithms.

Comment: 30m SRTM is now available at Earth Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Theres SRTM data available. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuttle_Radar_Topography_Mission for more information.

Note that SRTM hat a ground resolution of approx. 30 or 90 meters ( 1 and 3 arc-seconds, respectively). That is probably the highest-resolution free dataset available.

For more detailed DEMs you should contact local Nepali governments/universities.